# Как поменять значение src у картинки в Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, img

В Chrome работает такой код:

```
document.getElementById('captcha_img').src = '/captcha.php';
```

А в Firefox не пашет. Кто-то сталкивался? В чём проблема?

Comment: какую ошибку возвращает код в `Firefox`

Comment: ничего не возвращает. просто не меняет и всё

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это скорее все проблема с кэшем.

- Можно либо отключить кэш.
- `document.getElementById('captcha_img').src = '/captcha.php?rand='+Math.random();`